# How to compute distance between centers of each class?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning

I am trying to maximize the distance between two different class centres. I have centres of classes (MNIST) which is of shape `(10,2)` where 10 is the number of classes and 2 is the dimension. The computed centres is a tensor object. 
I have tried `tf.add(centres, margin)` to maximize the distance between the centres, but of no use. How can I maximize the distance between all the centres?
I am computing centres as:

`centers = tf.get_variable('centers' [num_classes, len_features], dtype=tf.float32, initializer=tf.constant_initializer(0), trainable=False)`

I gather the centres for the current batch and compute loss on those, now I would also like to maximize the distance between those centres. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What is a "center of class"? I have no idea what you're asking. Could you provide more context?

Comment: For MNIST, we have 10 classes i.e. 0,1,2,3...9. For each class, we have 6000 images, a total of 60k images. A class centre would be the centre of deep features of each class.

Comment: Ok we probably still need a deeper understanding of what your model is and what you're trying. Even current results if you have some. Include that to your question

Comment: "centre of deep features" still doesn't explain "centre"; you've merely changed the level of description.

Comment: I am training a neural network (LeNet) with customized loss function. However, instead of just softmax, I want to maximize the distance between the centres so as to minimize the interclass variations and maximize the interclass distance.

Comment: Then what you should be using is either a clustering algorithm or Fisher's LDA (Linear Discriminant Analysis) instead of neural networks.